# Where does the variable "p" get it's value from in ruby if it's not defined explicitly?

Tags: ruby, jruby, irb

**Question: Where does `p` get it's value from below and why does it happen?**

Consider this irb session:

```
me@somewhere:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> a
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> foo
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0> p
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> p.class
=> NilClass
irb(main):005:0>
```

I never defined `p` - so why is it nil valued? Neither `a` nor `foo` were recognized so what's special about `p`? I also didn't find anything listed under `Kernel#p`

**Context:** I'm reading the so-called ["28 bytes of ruby joy"](http://rbjl.net/26-the-28-bytes-of-ruby-joy) and assumed `p` was a variable, as in: `def p.method_missing *_` ...

(Don't worry: I'm not going to actually define method_missing on nil everywhere... just studying some ruby code...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p` is just a method on **[`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html)** which calls `inspect` on its arguments, producing human-readable representations of those objects. If you give it no arguments, it prints nothing. Regardless of what you pass it, though, it returns `nil`. See **[`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005961)** and **[`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000360)**.

**Power tip:** In Ruby 1.9, when you have a method and you don't know where it came from, use the `method` method:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 > method(:p)
 => #<Method: Object(Kernel)#p>
```

Putting it together one step at a time, we read this as:

```
 p                            # We found a method called p.
 #p                           # It's an instance method.
 Object ... #p                # It's available on Object.
 Object(Kernel)#p             # It came from the Kernel module.
```

---

**Update:** The OP provided some context from **[this article](http://rbjl.net/26-the-28-bytes-of-ruby-joy)**, where the author claims that your life will be easier if you add a `method_missing` to `nil`, by doing the following:

```
def p.method_missing*_;p;end
```

This somewhat obfuscated code should be read as:

- Define a new method (`def`), called `method_missing`. This overrides the default `method_missing` handler on `Object`, which simply raises a `NoMethodError` when it encounters a method it doesn't understand.
- This method will live on something called `p`.
- It accepts any number of arguments (`*`) and stores them in a variable called `_`.
- The result of these arguments is something called `p`.

The second bullet is the tricky part here. `def p.method_missing` means one of two things, depending on context:

- A previously defined object called `p` which is in scope here.
- A method called `p` which is in scope, and which is passed no arguments.

With `def p.method_missing`, we mean, "this method is being defined on the object which is the result of calling `p` with no arguments". In this case, that is `NilClass`; if you call `p` with no arguments, you get `nil`. So this is just a short, hacky way to define a method on `NilClass`.

**Note:** I definitely recommend *against* defining a `method_missing` on `nil`. This is a silly and dangerous tactic to use for the sake of saving a few lines of code, because it changes the behavior of `nil`. Don't do it!

Comment: I Agree: I think the 28 bytes approach is interesting from a design point of view but it's dangerous to change such a global assumption given __other people might be relying on exceptions caused by messaging nil__. (It's from the "oh no! - they've discovered meta-programming" school of maintenance problems...)

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a method which prints the `inspect` value of its arguments and returns nil. Without arguments it simply does nothing.

Its documentation is under `Kernel#p`, not `Kernel::p` (because it's an instance method of Kernel).

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a method of the `Kernel` module. It's good for debugging - it prints out the internal representation of whatever you give it, by calling `inspect` on it. If you don't pass it any arguments, it just prints out `nil`.

```
irb(main):001:0> p 11
11
=> 11
irb(main):002:0> Kernel::p [1,2] + [3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The results are printed out twice here as it also returns the object, which irb then prints out too.

Comment: It actually prints nothing if given no arguments.  `nil` is it's return value.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005961